# Adding Firebase to Angular 2 Tour of Heroes Tutorial

Tags: firebase, angular, angularfire

I'm trying to connect firebase to the angular2 tour of heroes tutorial by John Papa and I can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried to follow and implement jeffbcross in his angular2 example [here](https://github.com/jeffbcross/angularfire2) , but I can't quite get it to work. I'm trying to create a simple example of angular2 and firebase playing nice together, and it would be really cool if it included OAuth. Does anyone know how to hook this up or have a repo of this?

After trying to use jeffbcross's example, I got stuck here: [github.com/LukeSchlangen/heroesOfFirebase](http://github.com/LukeSchlangen/heroesOfFirebase) I couldn't get all of the references and imports working. Specifically, `import * as Firebase from 'firebase';` would keep showing that I have `'firebase'` as undefined, which makes sense because I never exported it, but I don't know where to export it.

(In case it helps, I'm using Visual Studio Code and the exact error is "Cannot find module 'firebase'")

Comment: After trying to use jeffbcross's example, I got stuck here: https://github.com/LukeSchlangen/heroesOfFirebase

I couldn't get all of the references and imports working.

Specifically, `import * as Firebase from 'firebase';` would keep showing that I have `'firebase'` as undefined, which makes sense because I never exported it, but I don't know where to export it.

Comment: can you provide a plunker? https://plnkr.co

Comment: I can't right now, but this is a plunker of tour of heroes without any connection to firebase: http://plnkr.co/edit/rUOZ12VN26LYPw0SqbQD?p=preview

Comment: think this might help you, its the ng2 todo app connected with firebase made by a key member of the team i suppose `https://github.com/davideast/ng2do` demo: `https://vivid-fire-4950.firebaseapp.com/`

Comment: check this as well `https://github.com/r-park/todo-angular2-firebase`

Comment: David East's ng2do seems like an interesting example and definitely the kind of thing I'm interested in, but when I tried running it locally, I found it isn't working any more. There is a pull request that tries to fix it, but even with those changes, I couldn't get it working. It's been 11 months since David updated it, so it seems like it's not maintained at this point?

The r-park todo repo is almost exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much for finding that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YET ANOTHER UPDATE: Folks should take a look at the new AngularFire project (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2 and https://angularfire2.com/api/) which is currently in beta. This module takes care of a lot of issues that everyone is facing.

Take a look at jeffbcross's [typings.json](https://github.com/jeffbcross/angularfire2/blob/master/typings.json) file. That is where the compiler is getting the 'firebase' reference.

UPDATE: In the case of this repo, the original author has a script cited in the package.json named "install_typings" which can be invoked using:

```
npm run install_typings
```

This will install [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) which will help is "the manager for Typescript definitions." You could also install typings the normal way:

```
npm install typings --global
```

To get the Firebase definitions installed I needed to run this command:

```
typings install firebase --ambient --save
```

The result should give you a new folder on the root of the project named "typings" with files and folders inside.

I hope this helps, given that I've had a difficult time getting **any** of the Angular 2 with Firebase examples working at all. The one I've had the best success with has been r-park's [todo-angular2-firebase](https://github.com/r-park/todo-angular2-firebase) repo.

Good luck.

Comment: That makes sense! I added it to the app folder and to the root folder and checked the angularfire.ts file and I was still getting the error. It makes total sense that this should fix it, but I think I'm still missing something.

Comment: I still can't seem to get the Angular 2 and Tour of Heroes to work. I've had the same trouble getting any of the Angular 2 and Firebase examples to work and I definitely think r-park's is the way to go for now. I think "use r-park's example" is probably the moral of the story for today, I think that will probably change a lot in the coming months, but I think that makes yours the right answer. Thank you!!